# c# defaults to c/# in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, search, default-settings

Whenever I enter a search starting with c# in my browser bar at the top of chrome (which is very often), after I press enter, it changes to c/#.  I have no idea why.  It did not use to do this.  It then links to a website which could not be found.  Any idea on how to make this stop?

Comment: Which Chrome version are you currently using?

Answer (score 1):

Could be the *prediction service* is enabled in your Chrome browser.
This is done by default.

To disable it:

- Click the Chrome menu on the browser toolbar (upper right).
- Select *Settings*.
- Click *Show advanced settings*.
- In the "Privacy" section, deselect the "Use a prediction service to help complete searches and URLs typed in the address bar" checkbox.

You should then also clear your browser historie.
How to do that you can find here:  [at Google Support](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95537)

Comment: i want to keep predictions on, and clearing history didnt fix it :( thanks tho